# Adding & Removing values from pandas dataframe or CSV with reference dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Fairly specific problem here - Below is the code i'm currently using that has a two inputs:

- A reference dictionary that has a single code as the keys, and the values being lists of 1-10 numbers
- A pandas df, that looks something like this:

| week | day | country | size | code | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W1 | Tu | US | M | 1 | 8 |
| W1 | Tu | CA | M | 2 | 4 |
| W1 | Tu | US | M | 10 | 13 |
| W1 | Tu | US | M | 20 | 2 |
| W1 | Tu | CA | M | 20 | 16 |
| W1 | W | US | M | 30 | 9 |

Expected output:

| week | day | country | contsize | code | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W1 | Tu | US | M | 10 | 21 |
| W1 | Tu | US | M | 20 | 10 |
| W1 | Tu | CA | M | 20 | 20 |
| W1 | W | US | M | 30 | 9 |

What i'm trying to do is move take the totals from rows in the diciontary and apply it to their values.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
# df
  week day country contsize  code  total
0   W1  Tu      US        M     1      8
1   W1  Tu      CA        M     2      4
2   W1  Tu      US        M    10     13
3   W1  Tu      US        M    20      2
4   W1  Tu      CA        M    20     16
5   W1   W      US        M    30      9

# ref_dict
{1: ['10', '20', '30'],
 2: ['10', '20'],
 3: ['20', '30'],
 4: ['10', '30']}
```

Doing:

```
# Create your mask:
remove = df.code.isin(ref_dict)

# Get the values from the dictionary:
df.loc[remove, 'code'] = df.loc[remove, 'code'].apply(ref_dict.get)

# Explode these values:
df = df.explode('code')

# Convert them to integers, since they're strings in your dict...
df.code = df.code.astype(int)

# Divide into two separate frames.
# Also, make them have an index of the values you need to match:
index = ['week', 'day', 'country', 'contsize', 'code']
remove_df = df.loc[remove].set_index(index)
df = df.loc[~remove].set_index(index)

# Sum the totals together, only those matching will be preserved,
# and reset the index back to how you had it:
df = df.assign(total=df.total.add(remove_df.total, fill_value=0)).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  week day country contsize  code  total
0   W1  Tu      US        M    10   21.0
1   W1  Tu      US        M    20   10.0
2   W1  Tu      CA        M    20   20.0
3   W1   W      US        M    30    9.0
```

---

Do not use `iterrows` or `iter...anything`. They're a trap and throw out the purpose of using pandas. If you absolutely need to iterate over something, use `apply`, but most of the time there will be a better method worth learning...

Comment: Thanks for insight - new to pandas.    
    
Copied this exactly, getting the following error: 'ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!' Been trying to diagnose this but no luck, any idea what could cause it?      
    
On a side note - if i were to include a column into the df that i didn't want to include in the matching, would that impact the ability for this to run?